# C# Show selected row data in a new gridview 1-1 relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm creating a simple Patient App. 1-1 relationship between patient and medical history record. When the app is started the patient are displayed. When one patient is selected and the button is clicked, the medical history for that patient should be displayed.

My problem is all medical history is being displayed rather than that particular patient.

```
          private void PopulateGrid()
    {
        var records = _db.GeneralMedicalHistories.Select(q => new
        {
            PatientNumber = q.GeneralMedicalHistoryID,
            MaritalStatus = q.MartialStatus,
            Education = q.Education,
            BloodType = q.BloodType,
            Pregenancies = q.Pregnancies,
            Tobacco = q.Tobacco,
            Alcohol = q.Alcohol,
            Drug = q.Drug,
            MedicalHistoryNotes = q.MedicalHistoryNotes,

        }).ToList();

        gvDemographics.DataSource = records;
        gvDemographics.Columns["PatientNumber"].HeaderText = "Patient#";
        gvDemographics.Columns["MaritalStatus"].HeaderText = "Marital Status";
        gvDemographics.Columns["BloodType"].HeaderText = "Blood Type";
        gvDemographics.Columns["MedicalHistoryNotes"].HeaderText = "Medical History Notes";
        //Hide the column for ID. Changed from the hard coded column value to the name, 
        // to make it more dynamic. 
        gvDemographics.Columns["PatientNumber"].Visible = true;
    }
```

[image]
[image]

The new code after implementing .Where(). C_PatientID is the foreign key from the medical history table to match with the primary from Patients table

```
 var record = _db.GeneralMedicalHistories.Where(q => q.C_PatientID == q.Patient.PatientID).Select(q => new
        {
            PatientNumber = q.GeneralMedicalHistoryID,
            MaritalStatus = q.MartialStatus,
            Education = q.Education,
            BloodType = q.BloodType,
            Pregenancies = q.Pregnancies,
            Tobacco = q.Tobacco,
            Alcohol = q.Alcohol,
            Drug = q.Drug,
            MedicalHistoryNotes = q.MedicalHistoryNotes,

        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You've selected the elements that you want to display in your gridview, but you have not set any sort of criteria for filtering the results of your query.

To do this, first obtain the ID associated with the record that you want to display—I'll call it `patientID`. Adding the `.Where(p => p.PatientNumber == patientID)` extension method to your query should filter your results to just the patient with that `patientID`.

[`.Where()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-6.0).

Comment: I understand that I need some sort of filtration which is the issue since all the documentation I've found only utilizes one lambda expression. I'm having issue with combining the .where into my code. @Scriniary

Comment: thank you so much this is helpful in a way. I've implemented the '.Where()' but I'm still getting all records since I'm using two different tables. I'll include my code in the thread.

Comment: @MoAI I believe the issue is that such a `Where` statement will include any patients that have a corresponding foreign key in your second table. What you must do in your application is determine which key was selected by the user, call it `patientID`, and include this in your code by replacing your current `Where` statement with `.Where(q => q.C_PatientID == patientID)`.

Comment: please bear with me.  `             var patientID = gvDemographics.SelectedCells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
                                  .Select(cell => cell.RowIndex)
                                  .Distinct();`Here is my selected cell to determine the row selected. When I compare it with `q.C_PatientID == patientID` I receive ` CS0019 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'IEnumerable<int>`

Comment: When you use `var` to declare a variable, the compiler infers the type by looking at the type of what is returned on the right hand side of the expression. This is why the type of `patientID` as you've defined it ends up being an `IEnumerable<int>`. Presumably, you are only interested in one record, so try adding `.FirstOrDefault()` to the end of your linq query to return just a single int. Also, your query returns row indices instead of the patientID. It's hard to say for sure without seeing the rest of the code, but you may want to replace your lambda expression with `cell => cell.Value`.